# Apple Watch console / device logs is empty

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-watch

In XCode > Window > Devices and Simulators, I can see console /  logs from iPhone just fine but I can't see any logs coming from the paired Apple Watch. In Console.app, it's even worse. I can't see any logs / messages from both the iPhone and the Watch. I have tried to restart my Mac, reconnect the phone, but no use. Any thoughts?

XCode is 9.2 (9C40b). iOS 11.2.1, WatchOS 4.2. OS X 10.13.2
[image]

Comment: Has the watch been paired with a new phone?

Comment: not sure what you meant by that but the watch used to be paired with my older iPhone and I unpair that and pair it with this new phone (as a new watch, no restoration from backup)

Comment: There's been a lot of flaky behavior with pairing and Watch debug.  One thing to try is using the watch on its charger.  It used to behave a lot better while powered this way, I assume because it would not perform as much power saving.

Comment: How do you prevent the watch from auto-locking itself while on the charger?

Comment: Same as if you are wearing it.  Remove passcode and set screen on time to as long as possible.  (These help with development too.)

Answer (score 6):

You can do it by installing `sysdiagnose` profile to your Apple Watch.

Download the watchOS profile from here:

https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/profiles-and-logs/?name=sysdiagnose

Add it to your iPhone and you will get the choice to choose "Apple Watch" to install it to. Once you install it and click "Done" then you will start seeing Apple Watch logs in Console.app.

Comment: While I did start seeing the logs in the Console app, I couldn't filter my logs. I usually add some kind of tag to my logs, to help me easily filter them in Console app... but when I apply the filter, nothing happens.. I get no logs. I'm 200% sure I used the right filter and verified that more than a dozen times (honestly). If I can't filter and focus on my logs, then Idk what's the point... this is a very unpleasant problem where I can see my app running, but I can't see the logs to confirm certain things.